# What is a USB wifi dongle/adaptor with drivers that integrate with AirPort?

Tags: wifi, airport, usb, hardware-recommendation

I've tried the D-Link DWA-131 and Ralink-based generic adaptors available on Amazon.com such as the Rt 2571/2573. After installing the driver, they all require you to use a separate configuration utility to see/join wireless networks. I'd like to be able to select a wireless network in the Network System Preference Panel like you can with an Apple-endorsed wireless interface. Thanks.